# Why am i getting an empty list instead of a list with elements in it while web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, data-extraction

So I am trying to scrape the countries name from the table in a website https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/25/covid-world-map-countries-most-coronavirus-cases-deaths as a list. But when i am printing it out, it's just giving me empty list, instead of a list containing countries name. could anybody explain why i am getting this? the code is below,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/25/covid-world-map-countries-most-coronavirus-cases-deaths")
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

countries = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": 'gv-cell gv-country-name'})
print(countries)
list_of_countries = []
for country in countries:
    list_of_countries.append(country.get_text())

print(list_of_countries)
```

This is the output i am getting

```
[]
[]
```

Also, not only here, i was getting the same result (empty list) when i was trying to scrape a product's information from the amazon's website.

Answer (score 0):

The list is dynamically retrieved from another endpoint you can find in the network tab which returns json. Something like as follows should work:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://interactive.guim.co.uk/2020/coronavirus-central-data/latest.json').json() #may need to add headers

countries = [i['attributes']['Country_Region'] for i in r['features']]
```